# View background image beyond screen size

Tags: android

I have a 1500x1500px image and i set it as `android:background` and set layout width and height as `1500px` in `FrameLayout`.
I want to see the whole image but I can only see a part of it because I cannot swipe to see the whole. I set the image as background so I can put buttons on the image.

How to view a background image beyond the phone's screen size?

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.finalmap);
    ImageView imageView = new ScrollableImageView(this);// or find it by id
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = bmp.getWidth();
    layoutParams.height = bmp.getHeight();
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ScrollableImageView (https://github.com/Egorand/android-scrollable-imageview/blob/master/src/com/egorand/scrollableimageview/ScrollableImageView.java)  for implementing scrolling of ImageView.

Example:  (Remove all LayoutParam import and then add this)

`import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

`Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.your_1500x1500px_image);
private ImageView imageView = new ScrollableImageView(this);// or find it by id
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight()));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Don't forget to copy ScrollableImageView class in your package !!!!

try like this

```html
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = bmp.getWidth();
layoutParams.height = bmp.getHeight();
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: thanks. I have read a lot of git repos that I can put in my android project but the problem is that I cannot add it to the android. I have tried procedures on how to add a library in android studio like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio. Can you help me how I can add/import a library like the class above in android studio.

Comment: For this problem, you have to just copy this java file to your package. and then use it.

Comment: ok. Btw, the `new LayoutParams` and `context` is in red line, I guess it does not read them. What would I do with it?

Comment: try Optimizing imports CTRL + ALT + O. and tell me what happens .

Comment: i optimized mainactivity.java but still both are in red line. it seems there is no library that reads them.

Comment: please if you don't mind post your main activity code so that i can get idea whtat's wrong

Comment: im using framelayout and i changed `LayoutParams` to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`. How about the `context`?

Comment: i have updated my post, u can see my mainactivity now.

Comment: now it just says `Unfortunately, App has stopped`. I have updated my post above, kindly take a look.

Comment: So until now, I haven't made it run. I don't know what is wrong and its hard for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

well i don't know if it's possible with background or not but you can achieve this by putting an imageview inside frame layout or relative layout with both width and height match parent scaleType set to fitXY.

Comment: Thanks but that would make the image smaller(not in size but when you view it). I don't want to set `match_parent`. I want to swipe over the image in 1500x1500 width and height.